# Java Synchronisation - Do I need it for this simple method?

Tags: java, synchronization, methods

I have a simple method which is called from multiple threads;

```
@Override
public Bitmap getFullBitmap(Filter f, ProgressCallback<String> pc) {
    // Requires synchronisation?
    Bitmap bitmap = fullMap.get(f.id);
    if(bitmap == null){
        f.setProgressCallback(pc);
        bitmap = f.e.evaluate(currentBitmap);
        fullMap.put(f.id, bitmap);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

As none of the objects used are fields of the class (Apart from fullMap) is it ok just to call this or might one thread change the value of **bitmap** for example, while the method is executing?

fullMap is a SoftHashMap which maintains SoftReferences of Bitmap objects indexed but the Filter's id that was used to create it. If that makes any sense.

I haven't had any problems but I thought I might need it.

Please ask for clarification if this is not clear, the question makes sense in my head ;)

**EDIT**

- currentBitmap is an object of type Bitmap, there is one bitmap in the system which is considered current and it's managed by this class.
- This code forms a very basic cache,
  the bitmap returned will always be
  the same for each id and is not
  modified outside of this method.
- By using Soft References in a
  SoftHashMap as descibed by [Dr
  Heinx](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue098.html) and a FIFO queue of hard
  references for the 10 most recently
  added I hope to avoid expensive calls
  to f.e.evaluate. That being said, the
  call f.e.evaluate will return an
  identical bitmap object if it is
  given the same input. After some
  thought it seems that synchronizing
  the method is a good idea as nothing
  positive comes of two threads
  executing this code for the same
  filter.
- In addition I made bitmap final as it
  shouldn't be mutated after creation.

Many thanks!
Gav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 threads could access the map `fullMap` at the same time. Both could determine that the map doesn't contain a value for the same key, each create one, and then write it back, thus inserting a key twice.

This may well not be a problem beyond one of efficiency. However it can be a source of confusion, and may cause problems in the future as your solution evolves (how expensive will it be to create these objects in the future? What happens if someone copies/paste the code somewhere less appropriate!)

I would strongly recommend synchronising on the above (most probably on `fullMap` itself rather than the containing object, but more context would be useful before deciding exactly what's required)

Comment: Instruction re-ordering isn't the source of the race condition you're talking about.  It's a simple multi-threaded race condition.

Comment: I don't think the double-checked-locking issue applies here, as bitmap is not a field. By the time the object gets in the map, it should be properly constructed. Further, adding a key to the map twice should only be a problem if for some reason you only want the first key-value pair's value. Otherwise, the second value will just overwrite the first. Still, I think you are probably right about synchronizing on the map, because put itself may not be thread-safe.

Comment: @Matthew - edited to reflect that insertion of a key twice may not be a problem beyond that of efficiency

Comment: I've edited further to remove the reference to DCL. You're right in that it only applies to fields

Comment: Two threads creating a value and insert theirs into the map is almost always a problem, because it means two different threads will have two different values that they believe are the same.  Only sometimes is this not a problem, and even then it's rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

SoftHashMap.put itself may just not be thread-safe.  SoftHashMap isn't in the standard library, but [WeakHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) is, and it's not synchronized.  Besides synchronizing the method on the map, you may want to use [Collections.synchronizedMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) to ensure other methods don't modify the map concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need synchronization, because you can have two threads decide that `f.id` is not in the map, construct and then add one.  Each thread will be returned a difference instance for `f.id`, even though the map will only contain the one that finished last.

At issue isn't the variable `bitmap`.  That is thread-safe as it's local to a single thread. However, access to `fullMap -- which I assume is a field of the class -- needs to be synchronized due to the fact that you're doing a "put-if-absent".

Assuming the cost of constructing a bitmap is expensive, the best way to do this is just to synchronize the method `getFullBitmap()`.  If it was very cheap to construct -- cheaper than synchronization -- then I would suggest always constructing the new object and doing [`putIfAbsent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) on a [`ConcurrentMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html).  But when the object is expensive to construct, this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If your method only uses parameters that are passed in and local variables, with no shared state, then I'd say it's thread-safe and no synchronization is needed.

Thread safety has to worry about mutable, shared state.  Is fullmap part of that object's state?  If yes, then you have to synchronize  its access.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for the synchronization path if the Bitmap returned is modified outside of the method.  You run the risk of 2 threads accessing the method above while the Bitmap at f.id is null, both creating one and adding it to the map, with the second one overwriting the first in the Map.  Now you have two, one that is going to be modified by thread-1 but go out of scope once thread-1 is done with its processing, and the other from thread-2 which will remain in the map and be provided to all future requesters.

Answer (score 0):

I' not sure about this, but AFAIK you could get thrown a kind of "Concurent Modification Exception" if you have code, iterating over the "fullMap". This must not be in your code, but could happen in the library routines for SoftMap. 
This might lead to your code breaking at runtime every now and then for no obvious reason, and without a good way for you handle the situation.

Just a complicated way of saying: "if in doubt, be carefull". 
BTW: don't think about performance first with todays computers.

Happy Hacking

Huibert Gill